# App login via database using unencrypted password

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, titanium

Fairly straightforward, my app requires the user to log in by entering a user id and password which is authenticated against a MySQL database by searching for an exact match in the users table. Currently, the form accepts the user_id (the primary key of the users table) and a randomly generated 8 character password which is encrypted using PHP's `crypt()`. I just have a few questions regarding this process.

First of all, more of a subjective question, I don't think entering the user id is very nice. Perhaps a username should be generated using the user's last name and first initial (eg. John Smith becomes smithj1). Thoughts?

Second, I'm not sure it's entirely necessary for the password to be encrypted. The information isn't really that sensitive and it would be better if the user didn't have to enter in a long string of alphanumeric characters. Would it be feasible to just generate a short string, maybe 4-5 uppercase characters (similar to the code Google sends you to verify an account)? In other words, it would be more like a passcode than a password.

Depending on the second question, this point may be moot, but since the password is encrypted using `crypt()`, I don't think it can be decrypted by Titanium (what I'm using the build the app). If I should continue using an encrypted password, what should I use to encrypt it such that Titanium can check the entered password against the database with?

Comment: Your ponints are not related to programming, but to your app itself. You have to design it for yourself, no one knows your app to be able to give answers to this questions.

Comment: Most things in your question are subjective, and like Joqus said, depend on your app, your users, and your requirements. I answered the question about crypt() below.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [`crypt()`](https://www.php.net/crypt) will return a hashed string using the standard Unix DES-based algorithm or alternative algorithms that may be available on the system.

You can either use Appcelerator's free Crypto module, available [in their marketplace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1882?restoreSearch=true#!overview), or you can search for [a JavaScript library that supports DES decryption](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20des). Either will solve your problem.